# Deploying an SSIS package with dtutil

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to deploy a package with dtutil, however I am getting an error that reads:

```
Option "-xxxx" is not valid.
```

This correlates to the `SOURCESERVER` pararmeter I am providing, which has a hypen in it.

```
$conString = "xxx-xxxx";
$dtUtilQueryToExecute = '/SOURCESERVER "' + $conString + '" /sql "my path" /exists';
$result = dtutil $dtUtilQueryToExecute
```

I think that dtutil is expecting a new parameter when it reaches the hyphen and cannot escape the hyphen even though it is in double/single quotation marks.

The reason why I am using dtutil is that I need to be able to deploy the same package to many other servers from one location.

So either I need to figure out how to escape the hyphen in the server name, or I need to use an alternative deployment method.

How do I escape the hyphen, or what alternative deployment method can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe PowerShell is interpreting the hyphen in the variable. It looks like the wisdom of the internet suggests permutations like

- $conString = 'xxx-xxxx'
- $conString = "xxx`-xxxx"

Also, no trailing semicolon is required in PowerShell

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Also a note to use the back quote on the semi-colon after `/COPY SQL`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method why not use SMO with Powershell. That wayyou can create a script to deploy your package and also create foders, projects, environments and SQL Agent tasks.

Here is an example of something I would use:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$target_server_name = 'target_server_name'
$source_server_name = 'source_server_name'
$target_database_name = 'target_database_name'
$source_database_name = 'source_database_name'
$environment_name = 'enviornment_name'
$folder_name = 'folder_name'
$project_name = 'project_name'
$ispac_name = 'ispac_name'

$variables = @{
    email_alert = 'xx@xx.com'
    email_error = 'xx@xx.com'
    email_reply = 'noreply@xx.com'
    smtp_server = 'outlook.xx.local'
    tax_rate = '20'
}

function Write-Message ($msg) {
    Write-Host ' [+] ' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
    Write-Host $msg
}

Write-Host 'Starting deployment' -ForegroundColor DarkGray

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null

Write-Message ("Connecting to integration services on '$source_server_name'")
$conn_str = "Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;" -f $source_server_name
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $conn_str

$namespace = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices'
$intg_serv = New-Object "$namespace.IntegrationServices" $conn

$catalog = $intg_serv.Catalogs['SSISDB']

$folder = $catalog.Folders[$folder_name]
if(!$folder) {
    Write-Message 'Creating folder ...'
    $folder = New-Object "$($namespace).CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $Folder_name, $Folder_name)            
    $folder.Create()  
} else {
    Write-Message 'Folder found ...'
}

Write-Message 'Deploying project file ...'

$path = "$here\..\path_to_your_project\bin\Development\$($ispac_name).ispac"
if(Test-Path $path) {Copy-Item (Resolve-Path $path) $here}

[byte[]]$project_file = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$here\crm_imports.ispac")
$dummy = $folder.DeployProject($project_name, $project_file)
$project = $folder.Projects[$project_name]

Write-Message 'Removing old environment ...'
$old = $folder.Environments | Select -ExpandProperty name 
$old | % {$folder.Environments[$_].Drop()}

Write-Message "Creating environment '$envionment_name'"
$environment = New-Object "$namespace.EnvironmentInfo" ($folder, $environment_name, $environment_name)
$environment.Create()

$variables.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $n = $_.Name
    $v = $_.Value
    Write-Message "  -> adding environment variable $($n): $v" 
    $environment.Variables.Add($n,[System.TypeCode]::String, $v, $false, $n)
    $environment.Alter()
    $project.Packages | % {
        if($_.Parameters[$n] -ne $null)
        {
            $_.Parameters[$n].Set([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo+ParameterValueType]::Referenced, $n)
            $_.Alter()
        }
    }
}

$reference = $project.References[$environment.name, $folder.Name]

if(!$reference) {
    $project.References.Add($environment.name, $folder.Name)
    $project.Alter()
}

$environment_ref_id = $project.References[0].ReferenceId

$job_name = 'job_name'
$server = New-Object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server $source_server_name
$Job_server = $server.JobServer
$job = $job_server.Jobs[$job_name]
if($job) {$job.Drop()}

Write-Message "Creating SQL agent job '$job_name'"
$job = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.Job -ArgumentList $Job_server, $job_name
$job.Create()
$job.OwnerLoginName = 'sa'
$job.ApplyToTargetServer($source_server_name)
$job.Alter()

$job_step = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.JobStep -ArgumentList $job, 'Run SSIS import_donations package'
$job_step.SubSystem = 'Ssis'
$job_step.command = ('/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\{3}\{4}\{5}.dtsx\"" ' +
    '/SERVER {0} /ENVREFERENCE {1} ' + 
    '/Par "\"CM.source.ConnectionString\"";' + 
    '"\"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={6};Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=my_app;\"" ' + 
    '/Par "\"CM.source.InitialCatalog\"";"\"{6}\"" ' +
    '/Par "\"CM.source.ServerName\"";{0} ' + 
    '/Par "\"CM.target.ConnectionString\"";' +
    '"\"Data Source={2};Initial Catalog={7};Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=my_app;\"" ' +
    '/Par "\"CM.target.InitialCatalog\"";"\"{7}\"" ' +
    '/Par "\"CM.target.ServerName\"";{2} ' +
    '/Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";3 ' +
    '/Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E') -f $source_server_name, $reference.ReferenceId, $target_server_name, $folder_name, $project_name, $ispac_name, $source_database_name, $target_database_name
$job_step.Create()

$conn.Close()
```